# Git post-update hook fails to execute 'git pull' using sudo

Tags: git, sudo

For a new web development project I've configured a shared repo with a post-update hook which automatically pulls updates into the web server virtual root.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /srv/www/siteA/ || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master

exec git-update-server-info
```

However, the web server runs suphp which enforces that each file is owned by the user 'www-run'. However since the post-update script runs within the context of the user who initiated the git push, updated files are owned by the user and not www-run. I thought the best solution would be to initiate the git pull as the www-run user using sudo so i updated the sodoers with the following lines ('webmaster' is a group which all git users are a member of):

```
Defaults:%webmaster !requiretty
%webmaster      ALL=(www-run)  NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

In the post-update script I changed the **git pull** line to

```
sudo -u www-run /usr/bin/git pull hub master
```

But i receive the following error on the client doing the git push

```
remote: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Since I have specified that in the defaults that a tty is not required and that no password is required I can't figure out why this is not working.

Comment: `requiretty` defaults to off anyway, so you shouldn't need that line.  The error you're seeing would be consistent with that line in sudoers not matching for some reason - just guessing, is it possible that the group is actually called `webmasters` rather than `webmaster`, or that the other user is really `www-data` rather than `www-run` or something?  If you add the command `groups` at the top of your hook script, is the group definitely listed in the output from the remote?

Comment: @MarkLongair - Thank you. I can run the command manually as a member of the webmaster group and its works as expected (sudo -u www-run /usr/bin/git pull hub master). Sudo is therefor working, it must have something to do with the command being run remotely via SSH.

Comment: @Michelle did you ever get this working? I'm trying to update a repo from my laptop and keep getting the same error.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I answered my own question, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the ordering of the user specifications in the sudoers file. From the man page

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.
>   Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
>   necessarily the most specific match).

I moved the line below to the end and It worked.

```
%webmaster      ALL=(www-run)  NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: just a little question, is your repository in `usr/bin/git` ?

Comment: Samin, the above answer will run the git commands without password requred